# Automated Cropping of images using Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, crop

I'm trying to write a script to assist with my Industry Porject but I'm having trouble getting this code working. What it should do is take all Images in a directory Crop them, the crop being the same for every image, then export the cropped image.

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

filepath = "C:\Users\Ellis\Desktop\bunny_test"
os.listdir = filepath

# Loop through all provided arguments
for i in range(1, len(filepath)):
try:
    # Attempt to open an image file
    #filepath = sys.argv[i]
    image = Image.open(filepath)
except IOError, e:
    # Report error, and then skip to the next argument
    print "Problem opening", filepath, ":", e
    continue

# Perform operations on the image here
image = image.crop(261, 435, 153, 343)

# Split our origional filename into name and extension 
(name, extension) = os.path.splittext(filepath)

# Save the image as "(origional_name)_thumb.jpg
image.save("C:\Users\Ellis\Desktop\cropped", name + '_cropped.jpg')
```

Comment: Why are the bottom three lines of operation not indented inside for loop? This would only crop the very last image on the list :/

Comment: In what was does it not work? Also, please fix your indentation .. if this is actually how your code is indented you have an empty`for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were quite some errors in your source code.

- wrong indentation (though I think that happened when you copy-pasted your code, since the program above would not even pass the parse step)
- missing loop over filenames, do this with `os.listdir()`
- `image.crop` takes one tuple, instead you provided 4 arguments
- join path and filename with `os.path.join` (image.save does not take two arguments)
- it's `splitext`, not `splittext`

Here is something which should work:

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

filepath = "C:\Users\Ellis\Desktop\bunny_test"

# Loop through all provided arguments
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if "." not in filename:
        continue
    ending = filename.split(".")[1]
    if ending not in ["jpg", "gif", "png"]:
        continue

    try:
        # Attempt to open an image file
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(filepath, filename))
    except IOError, e:
        # Report error, and then skip to the next argument
        print "Problem opening", filepath, ":", e
        continue

    # Perform operations on the image here
    image = image.crop((261, 435, 153, 343))

    # Split our origional filename into name and extension 
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

    # Save the image as "(origional_name)_thumb.jpg
    print(name + '_cropped.jpg')
    image.save(os.path.join("C:\Users\Ellis\Desktop\cropped", name + '_cropped.jpg'))
```

Comment: Cheers hansapast this worked great !
Apologies for the poor source code, still a beginner when it comes to coding.

Comment: @EllisC glad that helped, and glad I could boost one your first projects. Everyone started once. Can you please update/accept the answer if you're happy with it?